# How can I get a notification email when a new release of GitLab is out?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce, gitlab-ee

As an admin of a private GitLab instance, it would be great to know when new versions are available, especially for security updates.

I couldn't find a way to subscribe to a "newsletter" of new releases and how important it is. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Use the release notification from project page: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab

click on bell and select `custom`, then you can choose `New release`. have pfun ;)

volker.

Answer (score 1):

GitLab releases a new version monthly, always on the 22nd of the month. This way you don't need to subscribe.

Still, if you would prefer a notification from GitLab, I would recommend to subscribe to [their release newsletter here](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/categories/releases/). It has two e-mails each monthy.

Answer (score 0):

GitLab releases a new version [every single month on the 22nd](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/marketing/blog/release-posts/#release-posts). You can check our blog [here](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/) and release notes [here](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/). You can also check what's coming in our [upcoming releases](https://about.gitlab.com/upcoming-releases/).